# Initialize Highcharts line chart from unknown number of points

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services, highcharts

I am trying to use the line chart in highcharts that updates every x seconds. Ideally I want it to initialize with some specific data and poll a webservice every x seconds, and update accordingly.

Currently I am just trying to initialize it with data from a webservice and am having some trouble. Depending on which option the user selects there may be one point of data at the end point, or there may be 500. I am trying to set up the initialization of the chart so it doesn't make a difference.

I can pull the data in fine from a temp endpoint right now, that only houses one point of data for testing purposes:

```
[
  {
    "time": 1432040070,
    "packets": 12
  }
]
```

I can `console.leg()` these values in the js and they appear in order, but when I try and push them into the data array that feeds the series, they are no longer there. I'd like the chart to work just as it does by default, once the data is loaded initially then it starts the interval.

This is the code I use for the `$http.get()` and setting the series:

```
$http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nodx").success(function(returnedData){
                      returnedData.forEach(function(i){
                        console.log(i.time);
                        console.log(i.packets);
                        data.push({
                            x: i.time,
                            y: i.packets
                        });
                      });
                    });
                    console.log(data);
```

The data I am "pushing" into the array is in the same format as it was before I changed the initial example so idk why it wouldne't be working. And [here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IPc1Yi8snFEU1zywav4R?p=preview) of what I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your original planker now (I took a short look yesterday) but I would suggest adding initial data after chart is initialized itself.

```
function initializeData() {
  $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nodx").success(function(returnedData){

    var newdata = returnedData || getMockedData();
    $scope.chart.series[0].setData(newdata);

    setInterval(updateData, 1000);
  });
}

function updateData() {
  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.random()*.5;
  $scope.chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}

$scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
         ...
          events: {
              load: initializeData
          }
```

You can check my plunker for a working example (I took a copy of yours yesterday) http://plnkr.co/edit/smkBEgiAtHBvxdulqMgb

Comment: so then could I do an `$http.get()` inside of either `initializeData()` or `updateData()`?

Comment: Yes. This case you are sure that chart is loaded.

In my example updateData content was snatched from your plunker and can be replaced with similar call as in initializeData.

Comment: Alright cool man. I'll try and get the `$http.get()` to work now. Thanks!